# Adding objects to an Array in a class from a test file?

Tags: java, arrays

Unsure on how i'm supposed to add to an array, i've been asked to fill the array from a test file but define it in class Patient. Any ideas?

```
   public class Patient
   {
   private String name;
   private int id;
   private int current = 1;
   public Patient(String name, int id)
   {
      this.name = name;
      this.id = id;
      Patient[] patient = new Patient[100];
      String[] Observations;
      System.out.print(patient[0]);
   }
  public String addPatient(String name,int id)
  {
     Patient[current-1] = new Patient(name,id);
  }
} 

// extract from class  PatientRecordSystem
public void addPatient()
{
  String name = "James";
  int id = 10122;
  Patient patient = new Patient(name, id);
}
```

Comment: you didn´t define the array in the class `Patient`, you defined it as a local variable for a specific constructor of the class `Patient`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are defining that list (or array) to hold Patient objects within the **constructor** of your Patient class.

That is simply wrong on many levels. First of all - one "Patient" should be exactly that - the representation of a single **patient**. When you go to the doctor and become a patient ... are you asked to know about 100 other patients around?! Then: that array that you define in the constructor ... just lives during the execution of the constructor. It simply goes away as soon as a call

```
Patient newPatient = new Patient( ... )
```

returns.

In other words: you want to think of **another** class that is responsible for "managing" multiple patients. And then you create "patient objects"; and tell the manager about them. And that "manager" is then using an array (or better some more dynamic List) in order to keep track of "managed" patients.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever Andrew said is correct , just making it easy for you. Use below code

```
  public class Patient
   {
   private String name;
   private int id;
   private int current = 1;
   private Patient[] patient = new Patient[100];
   public Patient(String name, int id)
   {
      this.name = name;
      this.id = id;

      String[] Observations;
      System.out.print(patient[0]);
   }
  public String addPatient(String name,int id)
  {
     patient[current-1] = new Patient(name,id);
  }
} 

// extract from class  PatientRecordSystem
public void addPatient()
{
  String name = "James";
  int id = 10122;
  Patient patient = new Patient(name, id);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

First you need to declare the array.

You can do something like:

```
Patient[] patients = new Patient[100];
```

if you know the size of the array.

If you want to build a dynamic array, because you don't know how many elements you are going to have, you can do something like that.

```
List<Patient> patients = new ArrayList<Patient>();
```

Then you can assign values to the array:

If you have declared a fixed array you can do something like that:

patients[0] = new Patient(name, id);

On the other hand, if you have declared a dynamic array, the code would look like:

```
patients.add(new Patient(name, id));
```

Comment: Just code, no explanations; and then absolutely **not** helping with his problems ... makes a very bad answer.

Comment: @Jägermeister you are right, I thought the answer was so clear that it didn't need any explanation. But let's assume that the person who asked doesn't know a lot about programming. I am going to modify my answer.

Comment: The person who asked said that he just started learning java. Plus: you **never** know who will be reading your questions / answers later on. You should **always** try to write something that matches the "level of expertise" that you can observe in the question. Besides that, your answer results in a "raw type" warning because you forgot the `<>`; and it doesn't even compile because there is no method 'Add()'. Guess what: it takes a bit of **work** to push your reputation; not just throwing some bad code at other people. And wow, even the reworked answer is still using wrong code.

Comment: Still using "Add()" ... hint: if you are serious, run your code examples through an compiler before posting.